# Redirect main page using nginx

Tags: nginx

How can in redirect `www.example.com` to `www.example.com/test` using `nginx`? 
The first is the main page of the web site, the second is a part in my web site.
I want the redirection only when user request the main page not other pages.

I have tried to do this:

```
server {
           server_name www.example.com ;
           rewrite ^ http://$server_name/test$1 redirect;
   }
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: What doesn't work about it?

Comment: Every things will be redirected. I want that only when you call the main page to redirect to the other page

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    location = / {
        return 301 http://$server_name/test;
    }
}
```

I used the `return` directive, since that is a bit faster than invoking `rewrite` with such a simple redirect. The key point here is to use the `= /` specifier on `location` block, which it makes it match only if the URI is exactly `/`, that is the root of the site.